# Copy and pasting renders script to be broken?

Tags: jquery, html, css, less, jsfiddle

At first I thought I reproduced the code wrong in LESS but then I tested it at jsfiddle as well but it didn't work however in the original copy it works?

Reproduction
HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head class="Setup">
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="../LESS/core.less"/>
    <script src="../JavaScript/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="../JavaScript/java.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="Setup">
    <ul>
        <li class="PsuedoButtons" id="Menu1">Source1</li>
        <li class="PsuedoButtons" id="Menu2">Source2</li>
        <li class="PsuedoButtons" id="Menu3">Source3</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Cut off unrelated parts

LESS

```
ul {
    li {
        display: flex;
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        height: 35px;
        width: 65px;
        top: 5px;
        background: #e6e6e6;
        list-style: none;
        justify-content: center; // Horizontal
        align-items: center; // Vertical
        opacity: 0;
        .rounded;
        &.show {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
    #Menu1 {
        left: 100px;
    }
    #Menu2 {
        left: 200px;
    }
    #Menu3 {
        left: 300px;
    }
}
```

JQuery

```
var debounce = false;
$('#Option1').click(function() {
    var time = 250;
    if (debounce == true) {return;}
    debounce = true;
    $(".PsuedoButtons").each(function() {
        console.log('hello');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).toggle(); // Sadness
        }, time)
        time = time + 250
    })
    debounce = false;
});
```

JF Fiddles
https://jsfiddle.net/b7jo7w4L/ : Reproduction
https://jsfiddle.net/7a1cpu0n/ : Original

Comment: The original has **external resources** with a link to jQuery. Your copy does not have a link to jQuery. The debugger would have told you the `$ is not defined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with js fiddle.  You need to load external resources (you're missing a reference to Jquery)